# How can you append text to the onClick attribute in an anchor tag using RegEx

Tags: c#, regex

Scenario A:

Given the following string:

```
<a href="#" name="xy" onclick="alert('hello');">test</a>
```

... I would like to use Regular Expressions (Replace) to append some text (ie: alert('goodbye'); ) to the onclick attribute and end up with an anchor tag that looks as follows:

```
<a href="#" name="xy" onclick="alert('hello');alert('goodbye');">test</a>
```

Scenario B:

Given the following string(note the onclick attribute is missing):

```
<a href="#" name="xy">test</a>
```

... I would like to again use RegEx to determine that the onclick is missing and insert the attribute with some value (ie: alert('hello'); )  into the string ending up with an anchor tag that looks as follows:

```
<a href="#" name="xy" onclick="alert('hello');">test</a>
```

I am coding in c#

What Regular Expression do I use to accomplish this? Is using Regular Expressions a good approach to solving this problem?

Comment: Hi, I miss the question here. Did you try to do it? Where are you blocked?

Comment: Can you even use Regular Expressions to accomplish this? If so, what would the regular expression look like? I am not familiar with Regular Expressions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example using Regular Expressions, this assumes that strings will follow the formats posted in your example and also that there will be no more than one link HTML tag per string -

```
void Main()
{
    //var link = "";
    var link = @"<a href=""#"" name=""xy"" onclick=""alert('hello');alert('goodbye');"">test</a>";
    var link2 = @"<a href=""#"" name=""xy"">test</a>";

    string s = AddJS(link,"alert('inserted');");
    string s2 = AddJS(link2,"alert('inserted');");

    Console.WriteLine(s);
    Console.WriteLine(s2);

}

string AddJS(string link,string js) {
    if (link.IndexOf("onclick") > -1) return Regex.Replace(link, "(onclick=\".*)?(\")(>)", @"$1" + js  + @""">");
    else return Regex.Replace(link, "(onclick=\".*)?(\")(>)", @""" onclick=""" + js + @""">");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No need for regular expressions, assuming the format will be simple.

This code worked just fine in quick test:

```
string sHTML = "<a href=\"#\" name=\"xy\">test</a>"; //onclick=\"alert('hello');\"
int pushAtIndex;
int index1 = sHTML.ToLower().IndexOf("onclick=");
if (index1 > 0)
{
    pushAtIndex = sHTML.IndexOf(";", index1) + 1;
    if (pushAtIndex < 0)
        pushAtIndex = sHTML.IndexOf("\"", index1) + 1;
    if (pushAtIndex < 0)
        pushAtIndex = sHTML.IndexOf("'", index1) + 1;
    if (pushAtIndex > 0)
        sHTML = sHTML.Insert(pushAtIndex, "alert('goodbye');");
}
else
{
    pushAtIndex = sHTML.IndexOf(">");
    if (pushAtIndex > 0)
        sHTML = sHTML.Insert(pushAtIndex, " onclick=\"alert('goodbye');\"");
}

MessageBox.Show(sHTML);
```

This will just look for `onclick=` in the string, then push the `alert` before the semicolon if exists, or the quote otherwise. If no `onclick=` is found, it will push the whole `onclick` before the `>` of the anchor.

Comment: This worked, however as you noted it is not using regular expressions. If it was possible, my preference was to have a solution using regular expressions. Thanks.

Comment: Why are you so eager to use regular expressions? Any reason?